# Accessing the app.config values from another project

Tags: c#, .net-3.5

I have two executable projects in my Solution. One is the primary program, and the other is only ran after a successful installation. The primary program (REase) has an app.config file that has the connectionString that the other program needs (DBUpdater).

How can DBUpdate access the app.config for REase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the method [`OpenMappedExeConfiguration`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.openmappedexeconfiguration.aspx) if the app.config file name for REase is known by DBUpdater.

Comment: I should be REase.exe.config, but it doesn't look in the right locations