# How to handle two or more app configs?

Tags: c#, app-config, configuration-files, .net-assembly

Lets imagine I have three projects in my solution. The first one is exe**cute**ble and the other two are class libraries.

Every project has it's own `app.config` file which contain some `httpBinding` data, some user settings and connection strings.

Then I build the solution and all I get (in the EXE's bin directory) is the only `app.config` file with the XML elements wich are related to the executable project.

So, the question. How do I suppose to use that another two configs (which are successefully built to their corresponding project bin folders?

Comment: Check out these SO Posts:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4547425/accessing-the-app-config-values-from-another-project  & 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2746797/c-can-we-share-some-contents-of-app-config-between-projects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the settings in the dll libraries in the `setting file of executable`. Or you can make a `separate libraries` for handling settings of all the projects in the solution. The default setting files look in to app.config.